# JQGrid: How to create a column with 5 choices ( 5 radio buttons)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a requirement to provide user 5 options for their input to a question.

How can I achieve this with the least possible code.

Currently I am using custom formatter. The code is quite horrible and thick.

I have seen

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ranking1_441.htm

the codes looks neat and nice.

Comment: It's not clear what you exactly need. Do you want to display the data? Which kind of "radio buttons" you want to use (standard `<input>` with `type="radio"`, [jQuery UI buttons](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio) etc)?  Do you want allow the user to edit the data? Which editing mode you want to use? Do you have working solution with custom formatter? Why the code which you use is not good?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice one for you to use :) If it is the table sorter you are after:
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

The implementation is there too and a demo

Comment: I will prefer a JQGrid Solution